# Adding SQL result table into mail message

Tags: php, sql, email

I want to add **this** table to e-mail message:

```
foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
        }
```

But something like **this** won't work:

```
$message = '
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hi, ' . ucfirst($name) . '<br>
      </p>
      <p>Heres the table</p>
        <table class="tables">' .
                foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
        }
                . '
        </table>    
</body>
</html>
';
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: are you sending correct headers with the html mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are echoing instead of appending.

```php
$message = '
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hi, ' . ucfirst($name) . '<br>
      </p>
      <p>Heres the table</p>
        <table class="tables">';
                foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
            $message .= "<tr><td>" . ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
        }
$message .= '</table>    
</body>
</html>
';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate the table into a variable, and then included that into your message...

```
foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
   $mytable .= "<tr><td>" . ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
}

$message = "blah blah" . $mytable . "blah blah";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure += is not a valid PHP syntax (Its valid in Javascript though). use `.=` instead.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. I was typing too quickly.

Comment: Heh , no worries. happens all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the assignment of a value to `$message`, e.g.:

```
...
<table class="tables">'; // stop here
```

THEN do your foreach, appending the results to `$message` via concatenation operator, e.g:

```
foreach ($songs as $key => $value) {
   $message .= '<tr><td>' . ucfirst($key) . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
}
```

THEN continue on with the `$message` string again:

```
$message = '</table>    
</body>
</html>';
```